# Centrino Wireless-N 2230 on Gentoo

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, gentoo

I am currently running a Gentoo on a Thinkpad T430u, embedding a Centrino Wireless-N 2230 card. The thing is I can't use my wireless card, even with the correct driver configs, and firmwares.

I have already done, the most relevant websites about the problem :
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi

http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Wifi

But I can't use my Wireless card on Gentoo (it works on Windows).

Here is a summary of my conf :

```
Device Drivers ->
    Generic Driver Options ->
        -*- Userspace firmware loading support
[*] Networking support  --->
    [*] Wireless  --->
        <*> cfg80211 - wireless configuration API
        <*> Generic IEEE 802.11 Networking Stack (mac80211)

        Optionally enable a Wifi LED:
        [*] Enable LED triggers

Device Drivers  --->
    [*] Network device support  --->
        [*] Wireless LAN  --->

            Select the driver for your Wifi network device, e.g.:
            <*> Broadcom 43xx wireless support (mac80211 stack) (b43)
            [*]    Support for 802.11n (N-PHY) devices
            [*]    Support for low-power (LP-PHY) devices
            [*]    Support for HT-PHY (high throughput) devices
            <*> Intel Wireless WiFi Next Gen AGN - Wireless-N/Advanced-N/Ultimate-N (iwlwifi)
            <*> Intel Wireless WiFi 4965AGN (iwl4965)
            <*> Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection (iwl3945)
            <*> Ralink driver support  --->
                <*>   Ralink rt27xx/rt28xx/rt30xx (USB) support (rt2800usb)
    Generic Driver Options--->
        -*- Userspace firmware loading support
        [*] Include in-kernel firmware blobs in kernel library
        (iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode) External firmware blobs to build into the kernel binary
        (/lib/firmware) Firmware blobs root directory
```

And here is my dmesg about iwlconfig :

```
[    3.002714] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux, in-tree:
[    3.004032] Copyright(c) 2003-2012 Intel Corporation
[    3.005420] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: pci_resource_len = 0x00002000
[    3.006736] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: pci_resource_base = ffffc90004fa0000
[    3.008032] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: HW Revision ID = 0xC4
[    3.009454] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[    3.009540] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1
[    3.011122] iwldvm: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux, in-tree:
[    3.012405] iwldvm: Copyright(c) 2003-2012 Intel Corporation
[    3.013668] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[    3.014907] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS disabled
[    3.016121] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING disabled
[    3.017324] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TESTMODE disabled
[    3.018518] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_P2P enabled
[    3.019684] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230 BGN, REV=0xC8
[    3.020968] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[    3.040687] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: device EEPROM VER=0x81c, CALIB=0x6
[    3.041832] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Device SKU: 0x150
[    3.042975] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Valid Tx ant: 0x3, Valid Rx ant: 0x3
[    3.044198] Registered led device: phy0-led
[    3.044246] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
[    3.044270] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
```

And ifconfig/iwconfig about wlan0 :

```
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 84:a6:c8:a9:3b:4d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0



wlan0     no wireless extensions.
```

If anyone has an idea ? Because seriously I'm lost.

Comment: It seems your driver and firmware is loading correctly. Are you sure about it being wlan0? What does iwconfig say by iteself (without defining an adapter)?

Comment: I have a problem with this card on Archlinux 4.1.3-1-ARCH x86_64, it fails to connect to my router if I put it in N-only mode. dmesg shows: denied association (code=18)

Answer (score 0):

Sabayon 11 based on Gentoo seems to support the Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN in my Asus U32VJ without problems. Networkmanager under KDE does the rest:

```
[19792.517227] wlp3s0: send auth to 00:14:6c:e0:f8:c8 (try 3/3)
[19792.717934] wlp3s0: authentication with 00:14:6c:e0:f8:c8 timed out
[19820.891907] wlp3s0: authenticate with 00:14:6c:e0:f8:c8
[19820.894747] wlp3s0: send auth to 00:14:6c:e0:f8:c8 (try 1/3)
[19820.898027] wlp3s0: authenticated
[19820.898246] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[19820.898254] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[19820.898259] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[19820.898505] wlp3s0: associate with 00:14:6c:e0:f8:c8 (try 1/3)
[19820.900754] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 00:14:6c:e0:f8:c8 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[19820.903800] wlp3s0: associated
```

There are hints that your drivers are more or less right:

```
lsmod | grep wifi
iwlwifi                57633  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              145999  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
```

The only disconnect is the inability to power off wireless either from the keyboard or Networkmanager.

If you like Gentoo then you will probably like Sabayon more.